# Pros and cons of using react's life cycle methods in arrow function format

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using the  public class field syntax (`handler = () => {...}`) to define all my React components' event handlers so that I can use `this` for my components without binding them in the `constructor`. I'm wondering can I use this syntax to use React life cycle methods as well? Say use `componentWillMount` in this way: `componentWillMount = () => {...}`

What are the pros and cons if defining react's life cycle method with arrow functions?

Comment: You don't need to bind life cycle methods

Comment: @HunterMcMillen I know that but the reason I'm asking this is because I want to keep the same function's declaration/expression syntax for my components. So I'm wondering is there any downside or strength in using the life cycle in this way?

Comment: There is no difference between them, so there is no advantage or disadvantage. I wouldn't normally expect to see a lifecycle method declared in such a way, but I don't think there is anything wrong with it.

Comment: Besides the answers below, I also find this article that helps me understand this problem: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/10810

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Each time your function performs a `=>` operation it has to create a new function object. This prevents the browser from reusing the same function when rendering multiple copies of the same element which makes optimization by the javascript engine harder to do. This would cause performance issues(, but in most programs, it won't be noticeable).

It is recommended not to use arrow functions for life-cycle methods in React

[When should you use arrow functions](https://reactarmory.com/answers/when-to-use-arrow-functions)

Comment: The last paragraph [here](https://dev.to/guin/learn-public-class-field-syntax-by-refactoring-a-react-component-njh) explains it better when it comes to public class field syntax.

Answer (score 6):

There shouldn't be a need in component lifecycle methods to implicitly bind `this` (ie: use arrow functions). They are always called from the context of the component, so access to props, state, getState, etc are already available.

So there are no advantages to this pattern. Some disadvantages I can think of are:

1. More verbose syntax that is [still just an ECMAScript proposal](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-class-public-fields/).
2. Confusing to other collaborators. If you are binding `this` on a component method, I immediately expect that is going to be called by some other entity downstream, ie: click event handlers passed from parent to child.