# Radiobutton on reload show saved value

Tags: react-native, radio-button, radio-group

I store radiobutton values locally using asyncstorage.
Everything is saved, but on reload I want the submitted option to be shown.
Like, if you selected "female" and you submitted, the next time you reload the page, the "female" radio button would be checked.

This is my code: https://snack.expo.io/@ursuoctavian/surprised-nachos
components/input.js

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
componentDidMount = async () => {
let getKeys = ["age", "height", "weight", "selectedItem"];
const [age, height, weight, selectedItem] = await AsyncStorage.multiGet(
  getKeys
);
this.setState({
  age: age[1],
  height: height[1],
  weight: weight[1],
  selectedItem: JSON.parse(selectedItem[1])
});
};
```

I think you have forgotten **JSON.parse** because white setting you used **JSON.stringify**. Try it out and let me know if you face any problem.

Comment: You should use `async componentDidMount () {`. Changing lifecycle methods to arrow functions can have unintended consequences see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48572190/5508175) for more details

Comment: it doesn't give me an error, but when "female" is saved, it shows that "male" is checked anyway